# Control WebView scrollbar position & color

Tags: android, android-webview

1. I have a `ToolBar` in the bottom of the screen that on click disappears or shows (depends on it's state), and I want the horizontal scrollbar of the `WebView` to be above this toolbar at any time.
   is there a way to implement this, preferably without javascript?
2. I have a dark theme which makes the web page background black, and it disappears the scrollbars. is there a way to change it's color?

Answer (score 0):

drawable/custom_scrollbar_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@color/gray"
    android:startColor="@color/gray" />
   <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

drawable/custom_scrollbar_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:endColor="@color/green"
    android:startColor="@color/green" />

<corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Just add

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_thumb"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_track"
```

attributes to webview in layout file. Of course i had to remove corners attributes from drawable files.